# Brew Install Error Xcode alone is not sufficient on Sierra

Tags: xcode, macos, homebrew

I'm attempting to install a package on Mac OSX Serra v10.12.6 running xCode v9.1 using HomeBrew v1.3.8.

The install and error is

```
TS-Mac-Pro > brew install dos2unix
Error: Xcode alone is not sufficient on Sierra.
Install the Command Line Tools:
  xcode-select --install
```

Then I run the command

```
xcode-select --install
```

which says the command line tool package is not available from the software update server.

Which I go into xCode it shows that the command line tools are installed.

```
TS-Mac-Pro > xcode-select -p
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Theo

Answer (score 17):

I went to Apple Developer website and downloaded the Command Line Tools dmg directly. An Apple account first needs to be setup.

The Command Line Tools can be found under -

https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Install downloaded dmg and volia - HomeBrew is back up and running.

Comment: I was having the same issue while trying to brew upgrade mysql. This fixed it for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I just fixed this issue by deleting the current install of the command line tools and reinstalling them. See commands below:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
sudo xcode-select --install
```

This fixed the issue for me in the end